# Minimising a function using scipy.optimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

[image]

I need to minimise the above function using scipy.

My Input Data

```
np.random.seed(1234)
m = 500    #500
n = 100    #100
A = np.asmatrix(np.random.randint(low=-10,high=1,size=(n,m)))     
b = np.asmatrix(np.random.randint(low=500,high=1000,size=(m,1)))  
c = np.asmatrix(np.random.randint(low=0.1,high=2,size=(n,1)))
x = np.asmatrix(np.random.randint(low=1,high=10,size=(n,1)))
```

[image: function]

My Function and Gradient:

```
def func(x, A, b, c):
    fx = np.dot(c.T, x) - np.sum(np.log10((b - np.dot(A.T, x))))
    return fx

def grad(x, A, b, c):
    gradient = A * (1.0/(b - A.transpose()*x)) + c
    return gradient
```

This is what i have tried to run

```
scipy.optimize.fmin_cg(func(x + t*grad(x, A, b, c),A, b, c), x, args=(A,b,c,x))
```

Comment: Since you are using `np.dot` in your functions, don't complicate things with `np.asmatrix`.  Stick with regular arrays.  If needed add a dimension (with `newaxis`, `reshape` or `atleast_2d`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with

```
func(x + t*grad(x, A, b, c), A, b, c)
```

What is `t`?

At any rate, your call to `fmin_cg` is incorrect - the signature of [`fmin_cg`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_cg.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_cg) is

```
fmin_cg(f, x0, fprime=None, args=(), ...)
```

The first argument needs to be your objective function, `func`, the second needs to be your initial guess at `x`, the third (optional) argument is your gradient function, `grad`, and the fourth is the set of *additional* arguments to `f` and `fprime` (*excluding* `x`).

The call should look like:

```
scipy.optimize.fmin_cg(func, x, fprime=grad, args=(A, b, c))
```

---

However, this still won't work because of a problem with your array dimensions:

```
<ipython-input-49-bf5fa71345fe> in grad(x, A, b, c)
      1 def grad(x, A, b, c):
----> 2         gradient = A * (1.0/(b - A.transpose()*x)) + c
      3         return gradient
      4 

/home/alistair/.venvs/core/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.pyc in __mul__(self, other)
    341         if isinstance(other, (N.ndarray, list, tuple)) :
    342             # This promotes 1-D vectors to row vectors
--> 343             return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
    344         if isscalar(other) or not hasattr(other, '__rmul__') :
    345             return N.dot(self, other)

ValueError: shapes (500,100) and (1,100) not aligned: 100 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

To figure out why this is happening, we can set a breakpoint in `grad`:

```
import pdb

def grad(x, A, b, c):
    pdb.set_trace()
    gradient = A * (1.0/(b - A.transpose()*x)) + c
    return gradient
```

On the first call to `grad`, we see:

```
(Pdb) type(x)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(Pdb) !x.shape
(100,)
```

Somewhere inside `fmin_cg`, `x` is being converted from a `(100, 1)` `np.matrix`  to a `(100,)` 1D `np.ndarray`. For an `np.ndarray`, the `*` operator does *elementwise* multiplication rather than matrix multiplication, which will fail because `x` and `A.transpose()` have incompatible dimensions.

---

Basically you are running up against the fact that `np.matrix` is not fully supported by many functions in numpy and scipy that expect an `np.ndarray`. I highly recommend you switch from using `np.matrix` to `np.ndarray` - use of `np.matrix` is [officially discouraged](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#array-or-matrix-which-should-i-use), and will probably be deprecated in the not-too-distant future.

Your `grad` function can be rewritten as:

```
def grad(x, A, b, c):
    gradient = A.dot(1.0/(b - A.T.dot(x))) + c
    return gradient
```

... and your initial arguments as:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
m = 500    #500
n = 100    #100
A = np.random.randint(low=-10, high=1, size=(n, m))
b = np.random.randint(low=500, high=1000, size=m) 
c = np.random.randint(low=0.1, high=2, size=n)
x = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=n)
```

... and now your call to `fmin_cg` should work:

```
res = scipy.optimize.fmin_cg(func, x, fprime=grad, args=(A, b, c))
```